# Access property in Soap UI Rest Parameter field

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I'm using the open source versión of SoapUI for a REST request.

I read and generate custom properties in the test case in a groovy routine for Reading certain files:

```
context.testCase.setPropertyValue( "appId", "_some_id_" );
```

I want to access this property in the request params:

```
Name:        Value:
appid        ${appId}
```

This gives me null values. What's the nomeclature to access the `"appId"` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the property is defined at the test case level, you could use something like: `${#TestCase#appId}`

There are some more details at [Property Expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html) if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: Thanks good for providing the page with the reference!
That's what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have two way.

- In the field request message 
  `right click / Get Data/ CustomProperties / your property`.
  [image: SoapUI Steps for add properties]
- In the field write this data `${customPropertyName#propertyName}`

Comment: IN open source version right click->Get data option will not be there

Comment: My version to SoapUI is Open source. Please find the attachment.